# Default parameters in nested yaml pipeline Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have multiple resusable yaml templates to build my project using Azure DevOps. I want to let the default template values when I don't want to override it. The problem I have is when I nest multiple templates, it's not working as I expected, here is an example of my issue:

- task_template1.yml:

```
parameters:
  foo: 'data'

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs: 
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: echo ${{ parameters.foo }}
```

Inside a job_template.yml I call this task_template1.yml like this:

- job_template.yml:

```
parameters:
  fooTemplate: 'data'

jobs:
- job:
  steps:
    - template: task_template1.yml
      parameters:
        ${{ if variables[parameters.fooTemplate] }}:
          foo: ${{ parameters.fooTemplate }}
```

And then my global template:

- stage_build.yml:

```
stages:

- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - template: job_template.yml
    parameters:
      fooTemplate: 'hello'
```

So in this case, by default I expect that my variable `fooTemplate` will set the value of the variable `foo` inside my `task_template1.yml` to `hello` because I specify it.
But it's not the case, because it looks like `${{ if variables[parameters.fooTemplate] }}:` is evaluated before the build start so `foo` is set to `data` instead of `hello`. Conversely if I would like to keep the default value of `fooTemplate` (`data`) I just want to not specify it like this:

```
stages:

- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - template: job_template.yml
```

It looks like a problem of nested templates. How can I do to fit this two rules? Feel free to ask me some more details if needed.

**EDIT:**

I  always have this message : 'foo has no value: undefined'

Other case that I have, instead of a simple parameter:

```
parameters:
  foo:'data'
  foo1:'data1'

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs: 
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: echo ${{ parameters.foo }}
```

So for the job I have:

```
parameters:
  fooTemplate:
   foo:'data'
   foo1:'data1'

jobs:
- job:
  steps:
    - template: task_template1.yml
      parameters:
        ${{ if ne(parameters.fooTemplate.foo, ' ') }}:
          foo: ${{ parameters.fooTemplate.foo }}
        ${{ if ne(parameters.fooTemplate.foo1, ' ') }}:
          foo: ${{ parameters.fooTemplate.foo1 }}
```

And then same case if I don't specify the `foo` and `foo1` value I have the undefined error, instead of taking the default values:

```
stages:

- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - template: job_template.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something is wrong with your syntax here:

```
parameters:
        ${{ if variables[parameters.fooTemplate] }}:
          foo: ${{ parameters.fooTemplate }}
```

Try this way(according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters-to-select-a-template-at-runtime)):

```
parameters:
        ${{ if eq(parameters.fooTemplate, true) }}:
          foo: ${{ parameters.fooTemplate }}
```

It works on my side.

**Notes:**

You can have something like this:

```
parameters:
  fooTemplate: 'data'

jobs:
- job:
  steps:
    - template: task_template1.yml
      parameters:
        ${{ if ne(parameters.fooTemplate, ' ') }}:
          foo: ${{ parameters.fooTemplate }}
```

Now if you specify 'hello' in `stage_build.yml`, the `task_template1.yml` will output `hello`. And if you don't specify the parameter in `stage_build.yml` like this:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:
- template: job_template.yml
```

It will output the default `data`. Here're more details about [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) and [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes it works for boolean, but what about strings, or numbers, If you don't set it, it will be "undefined" and I don't find how undefined can be tested during the build.

Comment: I'm not sure about what  "undefined" means. `eq(parameters.fooTemplate, 'string')`?Could you share some details about how I can reproduce the same issue to check that?

Comment: To reproduce it, replace the enable value to  a string value and you will see that  the default parameter is not set inside the  task_template1.yml,  it will show you an example of undefined when  you not specify it instead of the default value

Comment: @fandro It could be better if you can consider adding the details in your question instead one comment. I think you should display the changes you made to the three scripts otherwise it's hard for me to understand what the real issue now you're encountering. Or change all the update all the scripts above to use string instead of boolean as example... thx...

Comment: Or similar issue like [this one](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/6629)?

Comment: Yes sure, I  updated the question with examples and explantations. I  think  it's not  a similar  issue.

Comment: Thanks, I will give some try and go back to you :)

Comment: Not working for me unfortunately, I  also added  an edit with another similar case that I have. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, as I know devops doesn't support format like `parameters.fooTemplate.foo`. I think it's the direct cause of your issue... Check [this topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#iterative-insertion).

Comment: Ok, that was my conclusion too, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: You're welcome. If this issue still persists to block you, feel free to let me know :)

Comment: It's not blocking me but it can help to have templates for clear and light. If you have an idea for this other question, in the same topic... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60993631/send-array-of-object-inside-custom-azure-devops-tasks-extensions?noredirect=1#comment107928618_60993631

Comment: @fandro Sorry for the delay, but the link above(extension) seems to be another different issue like this one and I have no good idea about that :-( Since this original issue is resolved(not sure if I understand it correctly), you can consider adding your own answer below so that we can archive that for you. Thx :)