# Send array of object inside custom Azure DevOps tasks / extensions

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-devops-extensions

I want to create a custom Task for Azure DevOps and I would like to have an array of object as parameters and use it like this in yaml:

```
data:
  - field1: "data1"
    field2: "data2"
  - field1: "data3"
    field2: "data4"
```

However I didn't found any avalable methods or examples for this kind of case, only simple array like `string` array. How an I pass a  listof object from yaml  to my custom Azure DevOps task?  Feel free to ask me some more details if needed.

**EDIT:**

For example, I want to send a complexe lisf of object:

```
data:  # Data should be an array
  - object:
    file1: "/myDestinationPath"
    file2: "/TheFilePathToSend"
    override: true
  - object:
    file1: "/myDestinationPath2"
    file2: "/TheFilePathToSend2"
    override: false
...
```

Then I expect to load it, something like:

```
let dataArray = task.getPathInput('data', true);
```

Where `dataArray` can ba a simple JSON array, it will be easy to manage after.

Comment: Could you update with one simple sample data you want it stored at parameter, and how to you want this array map into task argument?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I added an update :)

Answer (score 0):

Fandro, a suggestion could be changing the way you organize your parameters and use `taskgetDelimitedInput` function.

Assuming you are using [Azure pipeline task lib in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/tree/master/node) and familiarity with [Build task creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task).

Step 1) Define your variables using delimiter (e.g. `|` ) inside the `task.json` file.

```
    dataOrigin: "/myDestinationPath|/myDestinationPath2"
    dataDestination: "/TheFilePathToSend|/TheFilePathToSend2"
    dataOverwriteCriteria: "true|false"
```

Step 2) Edit your task file (e.g. `index.ts` ) you may use [taskgetDelimitedInput](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/azure-pipelines-task-lib.md#taskgetDelimitedInput), it returns the string array.

Step 3) Manipulate your values:

```
let dataOriginArray = task.taskgetDelimitedInput('dataOrigin', "|");
let dataDestinationArray = task.taskgetDelimitedInput('dataDestination', "|");
let dataOverwriteCriteriaArray = task.taskgetDelimitedInput('dataOverwriteCriteria', "|");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it can be a solution, I also imagine a list of string arrays dirrectly as parameter. I m surprise there is no other options available

Comment: I agree you may you string array directly, anyway this is the available answer for the current version of the API and JSON definition. In case you think it is a great improvement you may create a pull request on github or even a feature request! Cheers!